# JCL for a COBOL table read / insert program

Tags: db2, cobol, jcl

What JCL EXEC and DD statements would be required to run a COBOL program that

- Reads and inserts to a DB2 table
- has PCLog for good run and abends

I don't need the actual code, but I'm looking to know what's required in terms of exec statements. If possible, the DD's for the execs would be handy too.

Comment: You do need access to the actual code, though, to see the DD names you are reading from and for the "PClog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
This utilitit allows you to

- Execute DB2 programs in COBOL
- BIND to DB2
- Unload DB2 data

Comment: IKJEFT01 starts a TSO session under batch. You are essentially running a non-interactive TSO session here. Other options for running a DB/2 COBOL program depend on the targeted z/os environment. See: [Connecting to DB2 from your application program](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_caf.htm)